# Почему результатом кода является 11?

Tags: javascript

```js
let a = 1;

function foo() {
  a = 2;
  return 10;
}
a += foo();
```

Comment: А сколько, черт возьми, должно получиться?

Comment: Скорее всего значение к которому нужно прибавить берется еще до вызова функции.

Comment: @Igor, думаю он хочет увидеть 12 ибо в функции присваивает `a = 2`.

Comment: @OliverPatterson Нет, пусть он сам скажет.

Comment: @highpassion нет, не стоит. Tам нет ни локальной переменной, ни замыкания.

Comment: @Igor, я очень извиняюсь, а не могли бы Вы пояснить, почему там нет локальной переменной?

Comment: потому что нет var или let

Comment: в функции изменяется переменная из внешнего лексического окружения

Comment: @Igor да вы правы, я снова поспешил, ответив не глядя даже, еще и в гугл отправил, приношу извинения

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что `a += foo();` равно `a = a + foo();`. Здесь значение a берется раньше чем мы выполнили foo(). Так что берется значение 1, а не 2. Если бы в коде было написано `a = foo() + a;` то ответ был бы 12